# How Can I implement navigation Controller in iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I want to implement the navigation controller in iPad, I know that it is not possible in xcode to do the navigation controller in iPad, there is a thing in which I can enter the view controller and with the help of this we can do the coding of navigation controller.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use a `UINavigationController` on the iPad?

Comment: I think he meant when using a template in x-code, the nav controller option is only for iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that it is not possible in
>   xcode to do the navigation controller
>   in iPad

Just create an instance of `UINavigationController` and add the view on the window. **The same way you do on the iPhone**

```
UIViewController *aVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initX];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootVC:aVC];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:navController.view];
```